# Hermite Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

In a famous [paper by Ait-Sahalia](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1468-0262.00274/abstract) I have found this expression for the Hermite polynomial (pp 252, line -5):

$$
H_{j+1}^{\prime}\left(z\right)=-(1+j)\,H_j(z)\quad (1)
$$

where $H_j$ is the $j$-th Hermite polynomial. The only relationship that 
links $H_{j+1}$ with $H_j$ that I know is

$$
H_{j+1}(z) = z\,H_j(z)-H_{j}^{\prime}(z)\quad (2)
$$

which does not imply (1). More precisely taking the derivative of (2) I get

$$
H_{j+1}^{\prime}(z) = H_j(z)+z\,H^{\prime}_j(z)-H_{j}^{\prime\prime}(z).
$$

So I am wondering where relationship (1) comes from.

Comment: (1) is plain wrong with the standard Hermite polynomials. Test it with $H_0(x)=1, \; H_1(x)=2x, \; H_2(x)=4x^2-1$, e.g. $$H_1'(x)=2 \ne -1 = -(1+0)H_0(x)$$

Comment: I am realizing that in the case of physicists polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) something similar holds: $$H^{\prime}_{j+1}(z)=2\,(j+1)\,H_j(z)$$, but it is not still (1).

Comment: Your last equation makes sense if you look at the leading terms: $H_{j+1}(x)=2^{j+1}x^{j+1}+ \dots$,  and therefore
$H_{j+1}'(x)=(j+1)2^{j+1}x^{j}+\dots=2(j+1)2^{j}x^{j}+\dots \approx 2(j+1)H_j(x)$
But $H_{j+1}'(x)$ is positive for large $x$ and cannot be negative as (1) implies.

Comment: The fact is that the relation
$$
H^{\prime}_{j+1}(z)=2\,(j+1)\,H_j(z)
$$ 
is not approximated but exact for the definition of the "physicists hermite polynomial". I cannot see where (1) comes from, I doubt that there is an error in the paper, since this relationship is fundamental for the entire theory to be valid.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, there are simply defined as $(-1^j)\,H_j$, I choice that does not influence the orthonormality condition.

Comment: But then there is still a factor 2.

Comment: The suspected relationship is 
$$P_{j+1}^{\prime}\left(z\right)=-(1+j)\,P_j(z),$$ where the $P_j(z)$ must be correctly defined in term of $H_j(z)$. Take for example, $j=1$ you get that the first two poly are
$H_2(z) = z^2-1$ and $H_1(z)=z$ hence 
$$
H^{\prime} _2(z)= 2\,z = 2\,H_{1}(z)
$$
Now if you define $P_j(z) = (-1)^j\,H_j(z)$ everything is ok.